# jquery/leaflet issue - Using overlay maps in leaflet using check boxes and not L.control

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I am trying to use checkboxes to overlay different maps in my leaflet web map using jquery. I can't seem to get the 'overlay map' to show on the base map already present. I am very new to jquery. I am using one, just to test but isn't working

```
 <div id= "layercontrol" >
    <input type="checkbox" id= "layercontrol2">Topo Map<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id= "layercontrol3">Satellite<br />
</div> 


   var OpenTopoMap = 
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17,
    attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
}).addTo(map);


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#layercontrol2").change(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){ 
    OpenTopoMap.addTo(map);
    return;
}else {

    OpenTopoMap.remove();

    return;

    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/q8H8HqXlz0jMibwi7dRx?p=preview You might have been confused because at first your `OpenTopoMap` tile layer is already added to the map, but your checkbox is unticked, so the first time you tick it, nothing visually happens (it just tries to add a layer that is already added). But then removing and adding have a visual effect.

Comment: @ghybs I see, that works. Thanks so much

Comment: @ghybs I noticed after trying your solution , the map in the check box only works with the first base map in the control layer, I can see the attribution when I am on the second and third base map, but the overlay map doesn't show, do you know why?

Comment: @ghybs I have added a jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/gtdkxj8e/119/

Comment: Looks like a different issue. Please open a new question with relevant code.

Comment: @ghybs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679695/overlay-map-in-checkbox-only-shows-with-first-base-map